# Building a parent/child tree relationship

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I have a problem: build a tree relationship parent/child like this one:

[image]

Can you review this piece of code please since I am convinced it could be improved?

```
struct item {
    char value;
    std::list<item*> children;
};
```

I write a comparison function for a sort :

```
bool compareChild(const item *first, const item *second)
{
    return ( first->value < second->value );
}
```

a function to get the parent:

```
item *getTopParent(const char src_data[][2], int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (src_data[i][0] == '\0')
        {
            item* head = new item;
            head->value = src_data[i][1];
            return head;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Two functions to push the children:

```
bool PushChildren(const char src_data[][2], int len, item *parent)
{
    bool parentGotChildren = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (src_data[i][0] == parent->value)
        {
            item* child = new item;
            child->value = src_data[i][1];
            parent->children.push_back(child);
            parentGotChildren = true;
        }
    }
    parent->children.sort(compareChild);

    return parentGotChildren;
}

bool PushChildrenforAParent(const char src_data[][2], item *parent, int len)
{
    bool hasGotAChild = true;
    std::list<item*>::iterator itchild = parent->children.begin();
    std::list<item*>::iterator childLast = parent->children.end();

    while (hasGotAChild && (itchild != childLast))
    {
        hasGotAChild = PushChildren( src_data, len, *itchild);
        if (hasGotAChild)
        {
            hasGotAChild = PushChildrenforAParent( src_data, *itchild, len);
        }
        ++itchild;
    } 
    return hasGotAChild;
}
```

A function to initialise the "tree":

```
item* initialize_tree(const char src_data[][2], int len)
{
    bool hasTopParentGotAChild = false;
    //initialisation of the head
    item *head = getTopParent( src_data, len);

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        hasTopParentGotAChild = PushChildren( src_data, len, head);

        if (head != NULL)
        {
            if (hasTopParentGotAChild)
            {
                PushChildrenforAParent(src_data, head, len);
            }
            return head;
        }
        else 
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamal for the formatting. Just notice that the tree can be longer but we always have one parent and/not children.

Answer (score 13):

Some quick comments:

- Your code style is all over the place. You have three different styles for function names: `initialize_tree`, `PushChildren` and `getTopParent`, pick one and stick to it. I would recommend the last one.
- Your code looks more like C and not C++ with what I presume to be free functions.
- `item` is an inappropriate name, a more typical name is `Node`.
- You really should push the functionality to modify the nodes, or tree in general onto the `item` type and turn it into a `class` using member functions (methods).
- You are allocating memory with `new` but never freeing it with `delete` thus you are leaking memory like it's 1995.
- You are handling raw pointers, this is not recommended. Prefer to use the std containers or smart pointers for managing memory.
- If you feel that you need to explain something to the reader, that's usually a hint that your code needs better structure. *hint*
- `std::list` is slow, prefer to use `std::vector` on modern CPUs. Vector is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ insertion and removal at the front while list is \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$. However the cost of poor locality of reference on the list means that the cross-over point when the list becomes faster than the vector for just about anything at all is when you have about 100-1000 elements (depending on size) and are hitting the worst case for vector. Which I doubt you won't reach in your program. So unless you have a very specific reason to use `std::list` prefer a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use relevant `#include`s

Your implementation requires `std::list` so the interface should have the line `#include <list>`.

### Name classes wisely

The code currently uses a class named `item` which is a very generic word.  A more descriptive name would be `Tree`.  Also note that, while not compulsory, a common convention in C++ is to use capitalized names for classes, and lowercase names for instances of classes and other variables.

### Follow a naming convention

Some of your functions, such as `compareChild` use camel-case, and others, such as `PushChildren` start with a capital letter, and others, such as `initialize_tree` use embedded underscores.  This inconsistency makes it harder to read, understand and maintain the code.  Better would be to use a convention consistently.  There are many different ones out there and some, such as Google's are [available on the web](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Naming). Pick one and use it consistently; consistent use is more important than which particular convention you use.

### Use object orientation

Because you're writing in C++, it would make sense to have methods that operate on a class such as `Tree` (using my suggested rename of `item`) be member functions rather than separate functions.  For example, when I re-implemented your code as an object, I got this:

```
class Tree {
public:
    Tree(char val) : value(val), children() {}
    Tree(const char src_data[][2], int len);
    bool operator<(const Tree &other) const { return value < other.value; }
    bool PushChildren(const char src_data[][2], int len);
    bool PushChildrenforAParent(const char src_data[][2], int len);
    std::ostream& printLevel(std::ostream &out, int level) const {
        for (int i=0; i<level; ++i)
            out << "   ";
        out << value << '\n';
        ++level;
        for (const auto &kid : children)
            kid.printLevel(out, level);
        return out;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Tree &node) {
        return node.printLevel(out, 0);
    }
private:
    char value;
    std::list<Tree> children;

    // a function to get the parent:
    static char getTopParent(const char src_data[][2], int len) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            if (src_data[i][0] == '\0')
                return src_data[i][1];
        return '\0';
    }
};
```

Note that one of the things I added was a means to print out the tree.  That kind of thing can be very handy for debugging.

### Avoid using pointers

Modern C++ doesn't really need pointers very often.  It's usually better to either use a smart pointer, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or simply use objects or object references.  For this code, that suggests that instead of `children` being a `std::list<Tree*>` that they would probably be better as `std::list<Tree>`.

### Avoid `new` and `delete`

If you don't use pointers, you have much less reason to use `new` and `delete`.  But if you do use `new`, each instance of `new` must be matched to a corresponding `delete`.  Often the best way to do this is to put `delete` in a destructor.

### Prefer `class` to `struct`

The only real difference, of course, is that by default, the members of a `struct` are public, while the members of a class are private.  Still, it's best to keep the internals of a class private to reduce linkage among objects to only what they need.  This simplifies the interface and therefore the maintenance.  If, for example, you wanted to use a `std::array` instead of a `std::list` internally to the `Tree`, it shouldn't require that any code using the tree is affected.

Comment: +1, but I'd recommend the name `Node` or `Vertex` over `Tree`.  This is because a `Tree` object *should* know how many vertices/nodes are in the tree, its maximum depth, etc.  All a vertex/node needs to know is what children it possesses.

Comment: @anorton: that's one way to do it, but it's also common for each subtree to also be a tree.  Whether that object also knows how many vertices are there is an orthogonal issue; one could easily write a member function for that.

Answer (score 5):

### Use `nullptr`:

`NULL` is a macro from the C library and its use in C++ is very outdated. Start using [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

### Use `auto` for compile-time type inference:

`std::list<item*>::iterator` is very lengthy and easy to mistype. This can easily be improved with the use of [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

```
auto itchild   = parent->children.begin();
auto childLast = parent->children.end();
```

### Use references whenever possible:

[C++ references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) are safer than pointers. You should give them the preference.

```
bool compareChild(const item & first, const item & second)
{
    return first.value < second.value;
}
```

Note: As @[Edward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39848/edward) commented, `compareChild()` should instead be a comparison operator of your type, in this case `item` (still use the references):

```
struct item 
{
    bool operator < (const item & other) const { return value < other.value; }
    ...
};
```

### Avoid deep nesting and return early:

Deeply nested logic can get very hard to read an follow. If you can return early, do so. It will make your code simpler and more straightforward.

Example with `initialize_tree()`:

```
item* initialize_tree(const char src_data[][5], int len)
{
    item *head = getTopParent( src_data, len);
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    bool hasTopParentGotAChild = PushChildren( src_data, len, head);
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    if (hasTopParentGotAChild)
    {
        PushChildrenforAParent(src_data, head, len);
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: Good points.  A minor note about `compareChild` is that it's better written as a member function operator: `bool operator<(const Tree &other) const { return value < other.value; }` with a reference as you note.  Done that way, `children.sort()` needs no argument.

Comment: @Edward, yes quite right.

Comment: Please note that `nullptr` and `auto` are only available in C++11 and above. OP is not tagged with C++11 so YMMV.

Comment: Yes, that's true @EmilyL. I'm never sure when to assume C++11 or not. I'd say it is likely to be the case, but there are some compilers out there that haven't caught up with the standard yet...

Comment: It may be that people new to the language don't necessarily know to specify C++11 or C++14, but they're sure it's C++.

Comment: It may also be a school course where only C++03 compilers are available.

Comment: I have started a meta discussion about this: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3745/39810